# Matplotlib inline in Jupyter - how to contol when the plot is shown?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a function that creates a figure and for some reason it is shown in Jupyter notebook twice, even though I didn't run `show` at all. I pass the fig and ax as an output of this function, and plan to show it only later.

I get confused between `plt`, `fig` and `ax` functionaries and guess that the answer is hidden somewhere there.

Here is an anonymised version of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
%matplotlib inline

def plot_curve(dummydata):
    # builds a chart

    fig,ax = plt.subplots(1) # get subplots
    fig.set_figheight(7)
    fig.set_figwidth(12) #set shape

    plt.plot(dummydata.x1, dummydata.y1,label = 'l1') #curve 1
    plt.plot(dummydata.x2, dummydata.y2,label = 'l2') #curve2

    plt.xlabel('xlabel') #labels
    plt.ylabel('xlabel')
    plt.yscale('linear') #scale and bounds
    plt.ylim(0,100)
    ymin,ymax= ax.get_ylim()
    ax.axhline(1, color='k', linestyle=':', label = 'lab1') #guideline - horizontal
    ax.axvline(2, color='r',linestyle='--', label = 'lab2') #guideline - vertical
    ax.axvline(3, color='g',linestyle='--', label = 'lab3') #guideline - vertical
    ax.arrow(1,2,3,0, head_width=0.1, head_length=0.01, fc='k', ec='k') # arrow
    rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((1,2), 2,3, alpha = 0.1, facecolor='yellow',
             linewidth=0  , label= 'lab4') #yellow area patch
    ax.add_patch(rect)

    plt.legend()
    plt.title('title')
    return fig,ax
```

and then call it with:

```
for i in range(3):
    dummydata = pd.DataFrame({
           'x1':np.arange(1+i,100,0.1), 
           'y1':np.arange(11+i,110,0.1),
           'x2':np.arange(1+i,100,0.1),
           'y2':np.arange(21+i,120,0.1)
             })

    fig,ax = plot_curve(dummydata) #get the chart
```

What should I change to not show the figure by default, and show it only by my command?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try disabling matplotlib [interactive mode](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode) using `plt.ioff()`. With interactive mode disabled the plots will only be shown with an explicit `plt.show()`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
%matplotlib inline

# Desactivate interactive mode
plt.ioff()

def plot_curve(dummydata):
    # the same code as before
```

Then in another cell

```py
for i in range(3):
    dummydata = pd.DataFrame({
           'x1':np.arange(1+i,100,0.1), 
           'y1':np.arange(11+i,110,0.1),
           'x2':np.arange(1+i,100,0.1),
           'y2':np.arange(21+i,120,0.1)
             })

# I'am assuming this should not be in the for loop
# The plot will NOT be shown because we are not in interactive mode
fig, ax = plot_curve(dummydata) #get the chart
```

No plot will be shown yet.

Now in another cell

```py
# Now ANY plot (figure) which was created and not shown yet will be finally shown
plt.show()
```

The plot is finally shown. Note that if you have created several plots all of them will be shown now.

Comment: still doesn't work. maybe an important part that I didn't mention is that the plot curve is imported from a separate  file

Comment: Make sure that `%matplotlib inline` and `plt.ioff()` are in the notebook (and not in some file you import). You want both of them in the very begining of the notebook before any plot.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
%matplotlib
```

With this importing you should not see the figure after plotting. 
But you can see the figure by writing `fig` to IPython cell:

```
dummydata = pd.DataFrame({
           'x1':np.arange(1,100,0.1), 
           'y1':np.arange(11,110,0.1),
           'x2':np.arange(1,100,0.1),
           'y2':np.arange(21,120,0.1)
             })
fig,ax = plot_curve(dummydata) #get the chart

fig # Will now plot the figure.
```

Is this the desired output?

Comment: Only partially. I then want to present 50 different outputs of ``plot_curve`` in a for loop.
but what is exactly happening? I get my plots shown twice for some reason

Comment: Hmmm.. That is weird. I tried your loop and I only get the plots once.

Comment: Do you mean that you got each plot once? I'm looking for something more controllable, like ``fig.show()`` but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Yes I saw each plot once. I will try something later this week. :)

Comment: @Dimgold Just curious, what happens when you remove the ax from the line fig,ax = plot_curve(dummydata) ? from the last line where you try to get the chart in your original script?

Comment: do you mean returning just the ``fig`` object?